# Need help to import .file into mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dump file with file extension `.file` with four tables in it. How can I import that file into mysql DB using mysql CLI client so I can start querying those tables?

I am seeing lots of ways to import `.sql` file or using load data local command.  I believe that wont work in my case.

Example: `full_dump.file`

Inside the `full_dump.file`, there are four tables: employee, customer, markets, revenue.

Comment: What's the content of the file?